# Missing close tag. SOAP

Tags: php, apache, soap

i´ve this problem using apache 2.2.21 and php 5.3.5
this is the end of the XMl

```
</env:Body></env:Envelop
```

missing 'e>'
i´m not found anything in google.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try adding the 2 characters it said you are missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only way to fix it:

```
class SoapClientParch extends SoapClient {

function __construct($wsdl, $options) {
    parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
}

public function __doRequest($req, $location, $action, $version = "SOAP_1_2", $one_way = 0) {
    $response = parent::__doRequest($req, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
    $response = preg_replace('/^(\x00\x00\xFE\xFF|\xFF\xFE\x00\x00|\xFE\xFF|\xFF\xFE|\xEF\xBB\xBF)/', "", $response);
    $response = mb_convert_encoding($response, "UTF-8", 'HTML-ENTITIES');
    return $response;
}

}
```

Finish code:

```
class soap {

private $_soap;

public function __construct($conn) {
    $this->_soap = $conn;
}

public function send_func() {


    $argumentos = func_get_args();
    $res = array();

    if (count($argumentos) == 1)
        $res = $this->_soap->$argumentos[0]();
    else if (count($argumentos) > 1) {
        $func = array_shift($argumentos);
        for ($x = 0; $x < count($argumentos); $x++) {
            $argumentos[$x] = "'" . $argumentos[$x] . "'";
        }

        eval('$res = $this->_soap->' . $func . '(' . implode(",", $argumentos) . ' ) ;');
    }

    return $res;
}

}

class SoapClientParch extends SoapClient {

function __construct($wsdl, $options) {
    parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
}

public function __doRequest($req, $location, $action, $version = "SOAP_1_2", $one_way = 0) {
    $response = parent::__doRequest($req, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
    $response = preg_replace('/^(\x00\x00\xFE\xFF|\xFF\xFE\x00\x00|\xFE\xFF|\xFF\xFE|\xEF\xBB\xBF)/', "", $response);
    $response = mb_convert_encoding($response, "UTF-8", 'HTML-ENTITIES');
    /* if (substr($response, -1) != ">") {
      //  $response .= "e>";
      $response = str_replace('</env:Envelope>e>', '</env:Envelope>', $response);
      } */
    return $response;
}

}

$conn = array();
foreach ($_config['soap'] as $key => $val) {

$conn = new SoapClientParch(
        $_config['soap'][$key]['wsdl'], array(
    "soap_version" => SOAP_1_2,
    "login" => $_config['soap'][$key]['login'],
    "password" => $_config['soap'][$key]['password'],
    "location" => $_config['soap'][$key]['location'],
    "uri" => $_config['soap'][$key]['uri']
        )
);

$_soap = new soap($conn);
$global['_soap'][$key] = $_soap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add `e>` to the end of your code:

```
</env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

Is there something else wrong that that is not working?